# Taylor series help showing expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Can someone explain to me why this is wrong, and what I should be doing? I think my method of taking derivatives and pluging in the given value is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: What you are forgetting is that the coefficients are not just the derivatives. There are some factorials that you are not writing.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{{n}}(a)(x-a)^n}{n!}\ne \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{{n}}(a)(x-a)^n}{1}$$

For $f(x) =\sin x$ and $a=\pi/2$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sin x&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(x-\pi/2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\\\
&=1-\frac12 (x-\pi/2)^2+\frac{1}{24}(x-\pi/2)^4 -\frac{1}{720}(x-\pi/2)^6 + \cdots
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. You showed it in a way that jogged my memory and now I remember how these work.

Comment: You're welcome very much! It was my pleasure.